# Remote gdb debugging does not stop at breakpoints

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, gdb, qemu, gdbserver

I'm having problems with debugging my modified Linux-3.11.0 kernel.
For debugging the code, I use:

1. GDB 7.6
2. QEMU 1.6.5
3. Linux kernel 3.11.0

My system has Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2760QM CPU @ 2.40GHz running Ubuntu 12.10

I compiled the modified kernel with a configuration file that I created using 'make menuconfig'. (with modifications in the "kernel hacking" category)

Some of the .config file lines (that I find relevant) are quoted here:

```
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y 
CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_FS=y
CONFIG_HAVE_HW_BREAKPOINT=y
CONFIG_HAVE_MIXED_BREAKPOINTS_REGS=y
```

I use qemu with the "-S" option to boot my kernel, and using gdb I connect to qemu and resume it's execution:

```
(gdb) target remote :1234
(gdb) continue
```

When setting breakpoints, for an example:
`break schedule` I get a confirmation message such as:

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0xffffffff81736400: file kernel/sched/core.c, line 2509.
```

So till here everything seems fine!

The problem is that gdb and qemu does not stop at the breakpoints!
They both simply continue running...

I tried to set hardware breakpoints as suggested in some places, but I get the message:

```
No hardware breakpoint support in the target.
```

which is weird because I have the CONFIG_HAVE_HW_BREAKPOINT set.

I also unset `CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA` as suggested in other places,but still no results...

I tried to mess around with the .config file as suggested here: [gdbserver inside qemu does not stop on breakpoints](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu-kvm/+bug/901944)  but I couldn't figure out the relevant differences between the working .config file and my .config file...  (There are too much differences!)

Can anyone please help me?

Thank You!!

Comment: How do you tell qemu that the running kernel is being debugged ? Where do you set the port "1234" ?. I've not used qemu before but, if you can, try enabling KGDB/KDB and running your kernel over a serial link.

Comment: I use the -s and -S flags. Qemu start and wait for gdb to connect on the default port - 1234.  Only when I press continue in the gdb side Qemu resumes its execution.   So the connection between gdb and Qemu is fine...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I found the problem so I'm posting here for other people:
Apparently this is a very delicate procedure... My config file was fine. All I needed to do is to define the breakpoints only after I connect to qemu, and not after loading the vmlinux. These breakpoints have to be HARDWARE breakpoints... otherwise they don't break!

Comment: If you're still out there...can you update this answer with an example?  It's not clear here what "...only after I connect to qemu, and not after loading the vmlinux" means.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, it simply means that you first have to connect gdb to qemu, and only then define the breakpoints...
If you do it in the opposite order - you will see messages that tell you that the breakpoints are set, but nothing will happen and it simply won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Mis-matched symbols also lead this issue. eg: you are loading symbols from host-side vmlinux, which is NOT identical to the debuggee.